# How to change background and foreground color of a Tkinter Window on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to set up a GUI window with Tkinter, but somehow I always end up with a blackscreen. Text is (if displayed) always black and so is the background color.

However, when I run `tkinter._test()` the buttons "Click me!" and "QUIT" are displayed properly.

Is this about background / forground colors, or am I missing something else? This is my code:

```
import tkinter

gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('Random GUI')
gui.geometry('600x400')

label1 = tkinter.Label(gui, text='Hello World', foreground='black', background='white')
label1.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

System information:

- macOS Monterey 12.3
- Python 3.9.7
- Tkinter 8.5.9

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the code:

tkinter takes fg as foreground color and bg as background color

so your code should be something like this :

```
import tkinter

gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('Random GUI')
gui.geometry('600x400')

label1 = tkinter.Label(gui, text='Hello World', fg='black', bg='white')
label1.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use MAC OS X.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

root = Tk()

B1 = Button(root, text='Mac Background and Foreground', bg='white',fg='blue', borderless=1)
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```